# Proguard : can't find referenced method 'android.app.DatePickerDialog access$000

Tags: android, android-studio, rx-java, proguard, android-proguard

I am enabling pro-guard in release mode but am getting this error after launching the app :

```
Warning:FormActivity$1: can't find referenced method 'android.app.DatePickerDialog access$000(FormActivity)' in program class FormActivity
Warning:FormActivity$2: can't find referenced method 'android.app.DatePickerDialog access$000(FormActivity)' in program class FormActivity
Warning:FormActivity$3: can't find referenced method 'android.app.TimePickerDialog access$100(FormActivity)' in program class FormActivity
Warning:FormActivity$4: can't find referenced method 'void access$200(FormActivity,int,android.widget.LinearLayout,boolean)' in program class FormActivity
Warning:FormActivity$4: can't find referenced method 'void access$300(FormActivity,int,android.widget.LinearLayout,boolean)' in program class FormActivity
Warning:FormActivity$5: can't find referenced method 'android.widget.LinearLayout access$400(FormActivity,int,java.lang.String,android.widget.LinearLayout)' in program class FormActivity
Warning:FormActivity$5: can't find referenced method 'void access$500(FormActivity,int,android.widget.LinearLayout,boolean,boolean[],int,int)' in program class FormActivity
Warning:FormActivity$5: can't find referenced method 'void access$600(FormActivity,int,android.widget.LinearLayout,boolean,boolean[],int,int)' in program class FormActivity
Warning:FormActivity$6: can't find referenced method 'void access$700(FormActivity,int,int)' in program class FormActivity
Warning:FormActivity$7: can't find referenced method 'boolean access$802(FormActivity,boolean)' in program class FormActivity
Warning:FormActivity$8: can't find referenced method 'boolean access$802(FormActivity,boolean)' in program class FormActivity
```

Here is my proguard file :

```
-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize
-optimizations !code/allocation/variable
#Start Project specifics

#Keep the BuildConfig
-keep class com.alouane.beapp.BuildConfig { *; }

#Keep the support library
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }

#Gson
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.dubai.fa.model.** { *; }
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

#Picasso
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

# rx_cache
-dontwarn io.rx_cache2.internal.**
-keepclassmembers enum io.rx_cache2.Source { *; }
#RxJava
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.ImmediateScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.TestScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static ** test();
}
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
    long producerIndex;
    long consumerIndex;
}
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
    rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode producerNode;
    rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode consumerNode;
}

-keep class com.google.**
-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.**

#Timber
-dontwarn org.jetbrains.annotations.**

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose

# standard

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
       public void *(android.view.View);
}
```

Most of libraries I used  : Rxjava, Dagger .. don't need to add proguard rules .

So .. DO you know how to solve this, as this is the first time I am using prougard for a release build. Thanks .

Comment: I'm having the same problem, only mine is with 'com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken getParameterized(java.lang.reflect.Type,java.lang.reflect.Type[])'. Just doing -keep class...... on the TypeToken class doesn't seem to work though...

Answer (score 3):

I hit this when I enabled Java 8 featuers for my project. Debug builds ran fine but a signed apk wouldn't build with `can't find ... access$100...` error.
A *clean project* made it work again.

In Android Studio try `Project` -> `Clean Project` - it should always be the first thing to try as it often fixes issues.

---

Although it's an old question it's the first thing I hit when searching for my error message - so I'll leave this fix here for other's getting here.